# Hglib: How to connect to remote repo using over ssh?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-api, hglib

Using "raw" mercurial API I can write just something like:

```
peer = hg.peer(ui.ui(), {}, 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/some/project')
```

After the connection is established, I can work with remote repo.

I'm failing to understand what should work with a remote repo using hglib.
Naïve approach, i.e. using something just as simple as:

```
hglib.open("ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/some/project")
```

does not work, and the exception raised does not make anything clearer to me.

My question: With hglib, how can I open connection to a remote ssh-repo?

Answer (score 1):

The hglib documentation is not very wordy about how to use it. The best is to already have your key copied and RSA fingerprint in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

But you can clone a repo with:

```
hglib.clone(source="ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/some/project")
```

You can of course add destination folder (e.g. dest="/path/to/blah").

If you already have an existing hg repo cloned you can change some settings in your hgrc before trying `hglib.open()`, so hg uses the ssh url like so:

```
[ui]
username = some_user

[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/some/project
```

**EDIT**
I think for hg.open to work, you have to have a repo checked out. For me I refer to the path where my repo is cloned. So:

```
hglib.open('/path/to/cloned/repo')
```

To do this over SSH you have to edit your /repopath/.hg/hgrc as mentioned above.